# XmlSerializer throws InvalidOperationException when having a namespace prefix in the attribute

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, xmlserializer

I try to read an XML file that contains the following element:

```
<ho:CODED-TYPE ho:BASE-DATA-TYPE="A_UINT16" CATEGORY="STANDARD-LENGTH-TYPE" ENCODING="UNSIGNED">
```

My class to describe this node looks like that:

```
public ref class FIBEXCodedType 
 {
 public:
  [XmlAttribute("ho:BASE-DATA-TYPE")]
  property String^ BaseDataType;

  [XmlAttribute("CATEGORY")]
  property String^ Category;

  [XmlAttribute("ENCODING")]
  property String^ Encoding;

  FIBEXCodedType(void);
 };
```

I get an InvalidOperationException from XmlSerializer.ctor telling me:

"Ungültiges Namenszeichen in 'ho:BASE-DATA-TYPE'." (this could be translated as "invalid character in: 'ho:BASE-DATA-TYPE'").

I also tried the following:

```
[XmlAttribute("BASE-DATA-TYPE", Namespace="http://www.asam.net/xml")]
property String^ BaseDataType;
```

But this didn't work either. This time without the error message but the unit test fails telling me, that the property is still set to "null".

I am completely stuck with this. So any help is appreciated

thanks in advance

EDIT: some more XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<fx:FIBEX xmlns:fx="http://www.asam.net/xml/fbx" xmlns:ho="http://www.asam.net/xml" xmlns:can="http://www.asam.net/xml/fbx/can" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="fibex4can.xsd" VERSION="3.1.0">

<fx:CODING ID="codingSpeed">
    <ho:SHORT-NAME>CodingSpeed</ho:SHORT-NAME>
    <ho:DESC>Coding for speed values within this system.</ho:DESC>
    <ho:CODED-TYPE ho:BASE-DATA-TYPE="A_UINT16" CATEGORY="STANDARD-LENGTH-TYPE" ENCODING="UNSIGNED">
    <ho:BIT-LENGTH>16</ho:BIT-LENGTH>
    </ho:CODED-TYPE>
</fx:CODING>
```

Comment: You are betting on different horses at once: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/asmxandxml/thread/b07be6c7-6a86-4a2f-be72-64972ff0b1ff ;-)

Comment: Yeah I know :-( Difficult to get an answer there and my unit test bar is still red, so I am frightened out of my mind :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*rewritten entire answer after edit by OP*

My original understanding of the error was wrong. The error is thrown on the initialization of the serializer, *not* when you read your XML. You cannot use a colon `:` in a name. If you specify a namespace, do not specify the prefix. Actually, you hardly ever specify the prefix (which is just a placeholder for the namespace).

After doing so, you already noticed that the value ends up `null`. The reason is that the serializer defaults to unqualified attributes. If you have qualified attributes, it assumes the attribute namespace is different than the element's namespace. This will work:

```
<!-- this works (if namespaces are indeed different -->
<ho:CODED-TYPE fx:BASE=DATA-TYPE="A_UINT16"...>

<!-- this works, unqualified name takes namespace of parent element -->
<ho:CODED-TYPE BASE=DATA-TYPE="A_UINT16"...>

<!-- this fails, because XmlSerializer does not expect qualified attributes -->
<ho:CODED-TYPE ho:BASE=DATA-TYPE="A_UINT16"...>
```

This seems an odd bug. Here's [somewhat similar report on this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816222)n at MSDN, which helped me to the solution. Just mark the attribute as qualified. The following works with your input XML (note `XmlSchemaForm.Qualified`):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FIBEX", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml/fbx")]
public class FIBEX
{
    [XmlElement("CODING", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml/fbx")]
    public FIBEXCoding Coding { get; set; }
}

public class FIBEXCoding
{
    [XmlElement("SHORT-NAME", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml")]
    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("DESC", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml")]
    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CODED-TYPE", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml")]
    public FIBEXCodedType Codedtype { get; set; }
}

public class FIBEXCodedType
{

    [XmlAttribute("BASE-DATA-TYPE", 
        Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml",
        Form=XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)]
    public string BaseDataType { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("CATEGORY")]
    public string Category { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("ENCODING")]
    public string Encoding { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("BIT-LENGTH", Namespace = "http://www.asam.net/xml")]
    public int BitLength { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Wooohaaa. There was an error in that post :-(

wait a second please.

Comment: @yas4891: please show the exact declaration of your input XML, including how the namespaces are declared. Also, show a minimized sample of input that fails you. Do you use a schema validator or is a DTD involved?

Comment: You really want me to post the complete XmlSource? That's roughly 7KB. 
How about we agree on the root element + the parent element of the element in question?

My serialization works so far for the rest of the document, but not for this attribute in the "wrong" namespace. I managed to get another attribute ("xml:lang") working the way described above, but it doesn't work here.

Comment: ok. I added some more XML code. This is the CAN-Example for FIBEX from ASAM

Comment: GREEN BAR! 

Thanks a lot! 
You're THE man! Definitely. I mean it!

Thanks Thanks Thanks!

Comment: @yas4891: glad it worked! Now, go ask some more questions and reach 15 points, so you can upvote answers that you like (i.e., this one ;)

Comment: I'll do in a minute :-) Got another programming problem right here at home :)